# Delphi чем выполнить HTML с javascript

Tags: html, delphi, indy

Что есть сейчас: локально сохранённая html страница с js, меняя в которой некоторые параметры получаем разное содержимое.

Что нужно: загрузить код этой страницы в переменную, открыть, сохранить получившийся код (результат работы js).
В идеале подошел бы IdHTTP (Indy), но не могу понять можно ли в него загрузить HTML код вместо URL.
Подскажите, чем это можно сделать (без использования элементов-браузеров)?

Comment: `IdHTTP` - не будет выполнять javascript. "без использования элементов-браузеров" - почему такое ограничение?

Comment: Если у вас уже что-то есть, выложите код, в котором у вас возникли затруднения.

Comment: Затруднения как раз не в коде, а выборе способа реализации, т.к. web-элементы для меня новая сфера деятельности. На входе у меня есть html код (даже не файл, а я его буду создавать непосредственно при выполнении программы), в котором изменяя параметры в js я буду получать разный результат... На выходе мне нужен html код полученной страницы (для дальнейшего парсинга), сама страница (визуально) интереса не представляет и нигде не должна отображаться. Скрипты Яндекс.Карт.

Comment: `Что есть сейчас: локально сохранённая html страница с js, меняя в которой некоторые параметры получаем разное содержимое` -- ты уверен что это будет работать? проверил?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроме браузеров - больше нечем, поскольку JavaScriptом занимается движок JS (например, V8 в Chromium) и API (DOM, BOM и другие). Парсинг HTML еще имеет смысл делать отдельной библиотекой, поэтому такие бывают. С большой натяжкой - CSS. Но JS со всеми API - это уж точно будет браузер.

Существуют браузеры, поддерживающие работу "offscreen", то есть без визуализации (хотя всегда возможен костыль типа убрать окно за пределы экрана и т.п.)

В Delphi можно использовать стандартный TWebBrowser, но это Осел со всеми вытекающими. Еще в Delphi точно можно использовать CEF через оболочку dcef3, он лучше, но мне тоже не понравился, есть шероховатости, годится только для таких вот задач, а именно для Web UI я его не стал использовать.
А лучше сразу работать с теми технологиями, которые пригодятся не раз.

"Рулит", пожалуй, Awesomium, но он только для .NET.

Так что, ИМХО, в идеале вам бы не только освоить "новые" для вас "элементы-браузеры", но и перейти уже на новый язык.
Ведь браузеры - это далеко не единственная проблема, которая легко решается на .NET и с трудом - на Delphi, с богатым прошлым, но унылым настоящим.
 Увы.

Хотя, и дельфисты все еще востребованы, но обычно на старых проектах.
Ибо зачем на ней писать новый? Как правило - незачем. Снова увы.

Comment: "Ведь браузеры - это далеко не единственная проблема, которая легко решается на .NET и с трудом - на Delphi, с богатым прошлым, но унылым настоящим." - над чем подумать действительно есть...

TWebBrowser - так и не смог подружить со скриптами, не все прогружает (просто скрыть сообщения об ошибке - не вариант)... Chronium в этом плане без проблем... С горем пополам смог получить код страницы НО: смотрю код в отладчике mozill'ы и из хрониума: не совпадают...
Очень грубо если сказать, то Chronium "не раскрыл" содержимое одного нужного блока.

Comment: @Антон Кроме инструментов, еще имеет смысл смена подхода к проблеме. Не знаю, как вы, а я раньше сильно страдал от прямолинейности мышления (оно же - "квадратно-гнездовое"). Когда выберешь какой-то один подход (скорее всего, удачный в прошлые разы), мучаешься с ним, стараешься тупо делать больше, зайти дальше, и даже не думаешь попробовать вообще иначе. Это срывает все дедлайны... Что у вас задача? Если классическая задача - создать бот для сайта с AJAX, и данные именно грузятся по AJAX, то браузерный движок не обязателен - еще есть вариант HTTP и снифферов с отладчиками.

Comment: Задача забрать тайлы карт с Яндекса и Гугла. Есть локальный html в котором прописываются все нужные параметры. Открыв его получаю изображение, при этом получившийся код содержит ссылки на тайлы и их позицию относительно заданных координат. Вот эту информацию мне и нужно получить (ссылка на тайл, позиция x, y).
Возможно стоит поискать другие способы получения ссылок на нужные тайлы...